# date reverts to US format in GB environment in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, date

Why does CDate and parseExact turn today's date (3rd October), represented as 03/10/2012, into 10/03/2012? I am using Windows 7, VS2012. All my settings in Control Panel are UK/GB. I have tried adding the lines

```
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", True)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", True)
```

with no effect.

Here is my code - you will see that I have to resort to swapping the day and month of the text version in order to get the date I want

```
    dim txtDate As String = "03/10/2012"
    Dim strOriginalDate As String = txtDate   ' 03/10/2012
    Dim dtmdate1 As Date = CDate(txtDate)     ' #10/03/2012#
    Dim dtmdate2 As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing) ' #10/03/2012#
    txtDate = Split(txtDate, "/")(1) & "/" & Split(txtDate, "/")(0) & "/" & Split(txtDate, "/")(2)
    Dim dtmdate3 As Date = CDate(txtDate)     ' #3/10/2012#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are looking at the date values in the Locals pane of the debugger. If you actually write out the values you will find they are as required:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", True)
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", True)

        Dim txtDate As String = "03/10/2012"
        Dim strOriginalDate As String = txtDate
        Dim dtmdate1 As Date = CDate(txtDate)
        Console.WriteLine(dtmdate1.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"))

        Dim dtmdate2 As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing) ' #10/03/2012#
        Console.WriteLine(dtmdate2.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"))
        txtDate = Split(txtDate, "/")(1) & "/" & Split(txtDate, "/")(0) & "/" & Split(txtDate, "/")(2)

        Dim dtmdate3 As Date = CDate(txtDate)
        Console.WriteLine(dtmdate3.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

The final line of output is, of course, not as desired because you have swapped the month and day.

Tested with VS2012 RC on W7 x64 set to en-GB. You might want to test with setting VS's locale: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9cytz106%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

The display of the date as a date literal is entirely consistent with how a data literal is defined, for example see the Format Requirements subsection of [Date Data Type (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)